# Devise Log Out link won't post to DELETE, only GET, which doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I see lots of people posting about this same problem, but none of the answers have worked for me so far. Here's what I've got:

In `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Which produces the following HTML:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Logout</a>
```

Unfortunately this is linking to Users#Show instead of posting as a DELETE to Users/Sessions#Destroy as it is supposed to.

My `config/routes.rb` has:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations' }

resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

And `rake routes` returns:

```
          new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                 users/sessions#new
              user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                 users/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                users/sessions#destroy
         new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
             user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                           PUT    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                           POST   /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
  cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  users/registrations#cancel
     new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 users/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    users/registrations#edit
         user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#update
                           PUT    /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#update
                           DELETE /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#destroy
                           POST   /users(.:format)                         users/registrations#create
                 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
                      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
                           PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
```

So the `link_to` `destroy_user_session_path` with `:method => :delete` should work.

My `application.js` has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require turbolinks
//= require skel.min
//= require_tree .
```

I also have the following in the `<head>` of `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

These are all the suggested solutions that I have seen, but none of them work. The only other solution I have seen enables a `GET` method to logout, but I'd like to keep it RESTful if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `resources :users`  - don't put the only conditions after it

Comment: No luck, still takes me to: GET "/users/sign_out" ...
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into this, check your developer console in the browser for any javascript errors. These delete requests are handled by a javascript controller and any errors will cause them to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]` and try if log out works.

Then see this doc : [How To: Define resource actions that require authentication using routes.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't help. I removed that line and it is still linking to a `GET` at `Users#Show`:  `Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-22 12:03:06 -0400
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"):`